# How to search in a JComboBox in a table directly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a table in which I use a JCombobox as an editor for the first column. I want the user to be able to start typing directly when the cursor reaches this column in order to search in the JComboBox without having to first press enter or space. To do that I override the changeSelection method when defining the table:

```
 public void changeSelection(int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
            {
                super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);
                if (editCellAt(row, column))
                {
                    Component editor = getEditorComponent();
                    editor.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
```

This works for the first column. However, I do not want the same thing to apply for the other columns, which are not JComboBoxes. I just want this overridden method to apply to the first column. I tried inserting a (if column == 0) in the method but that didn't work. Can someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by: _the cursor reaches this column_ Note: the _cursor_ is what marks the mouse location - can't quite imagine how that is related to selection :-) Whatever the requirement, it's highly improbable that overriding changeSelection will solve it (it's very rarely overridden)

Comment: What I mean is that when the user traverses the table using the tab button, I want him/her to be able to start typing directly in the column which is a combo box without having to press "enter" first.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method would be to override the [isCellEdtiable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable%28java.util.EventObject%29) method of the `TableCellEditor` class

Comment: depends on what the OP _really_ wants :-)